# Data not bind as it came from service in android

Tags: android, bind

Data is not binding in array list as it came from the `Service`, as like first option which added in `ArrayList` is `Lead`, second is `Qualified`, and third is `test`. When i check list on first position it shows `Qualified`, `Lead`, `test`. But i want as i bind my list as it show in that sequence.

```
public static HashMap<String,ArrayList<LeadData>> LeadDataMap= new HashMap<String,ArrayList<LeadData>>();
public static ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();



for (int i = 0; i < LeadListsJSONArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject Leadsobj = LeadListsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

//get stage name for hashmap key value..
String StageNameString = Leadsobj.getString("StageName");
String StageIdString = Leadsobj.getString("StageId");
System.out.println("stage id........................"+StageIdString);
//get new leads list..
JSONArray jaarr2 = new JSONArray(Leadsobj.getString("Leads"));
ArrayList<LeadData> leadDataList = new ArrayList<LeadData>();

for (int j = 0; j < jaarr2.length(); j++) {
    LeadData ld = new LeadData();

    JSONObject obj3 = jaarr2.getJSONObject(j);

    ld.setLeadCompanyName(obj3.getString("LeadCompanyName"));
    ld.setLeadId(obj3.getString("LeadId"));
    ld.setTitle(obj3.getString("Title"));

    leadDataList.add(ld);
}
//here we are puttin the leaddatalist inot map with respect to stage name...
LeadDataMap.put(StageNameString.trim().toString(), leadDataList);
//LeadDataMap.put(StageIdString, leadDataList);

}
```

In `LeadDataMap` data in not in that sequence in that i have put. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get solution by using LinkedHashmap.